# Class Name with a "+"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working on an iOS project in Xcode and I see some classes that have names with a "+"; for example:
`TableViewController+TableView.h` and then the class is named: `@interface RKTableViewController (TableView)` as opposed to `RKTableViewController+TableView`.

What is this `+` and the `(TableView)`? If its subclassing `UITableView` shouldn't the class be declared as: `Subclassed name : Parent class name` format?

Answer (score 5):

The + in the filename isn't semantically important. Naming a file "ClassName+CategoryName.h/m" is just a popular convention for naming files containing categories.

```
@interface RKTableViewController (TableView)
@end
```

declares a category called "TableView" on the `RKTableViewController` class. Categories are used to add methods to a class outside its main implementation. See the Apple documentation on categories here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: Why would you want to add methods to a class outside its main implementation? I don't understand why this complexity is required.

Comment: Because you add categories to classes you don't own. Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

These are categories. The are very helpful at times.

> You can add methods to a class by declaring them in an interface file
>   under a category name and defining them in an implementation file
>   under the same name. The category name indicates that the methods are
>   additions to a class declared elsewhere, not a new class. You cannot,
>   however, use a category to add additional instance variables to a
>   class.
>
> The methods the category adds become part of the class type. For
>   example, methods added to the NSArray class in a category are included
>   as methods the compiler expects an NSArray instance to have in its
>   repertoire. Methods added to the NSArray class in a subclass, however,
>   are not included in the NSArray type. (This matters only for
>   statically typed objects because static typing is the only way the
>   compiler can know an object’s class.)
>
> Category methods can do anything that methods defined in the class
>   proper can do. At runtime, there’s no difference. The methods the
>   category adds to the class are inherited by all the class’s
>   subclasses, just like other methods.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

**Example:**

Here is an example of a category I use all the time. I don't own NSMutableArray but I would love for there to be a simple move function. Instead of subclassing just to add a simple function I attach a category.

```
// NSMutableArray+Move.h

@interface NSMutableArray (move)

- (void)moveObjectFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from toIndex:(NSUInteger)to;

@end

// NSMutableArray+Move.m

@implementation NSMutableArray (move)

- (void)moveObjectFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from toIndex:(NSUInteger)to
{
    if (to != from) {
        id obj = [self objectAtIndex:from];
        [self removeObjectAtIndex:from];
        if (to >= [self count]) {
            [self addObject:obj];
        } else {
            [self insertObject:obj atIndex:to];
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to do new things with a class thats already been created all over my app. So anywhere I use an NSMutableArray I can call my added method like so

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object A", @"Object B", @"Object C", nil];

[myArray moveObjectFromIndex:0 toIndex:2];
```